# SWIG JAVA how to wrap C++ multiple inheritance with %interface and pure virtual methods

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, swig

I'm having a problem while wrapping a huge C++ code to JAVA using SWIG.

What I'm trying to do is wrap a Derived class that extends 2 other classes in C++, but one of the classes (Base1 on the example bellow), should be wrapped as an interface. (To account for Java not having multiple inheritance).

I've found the problem and created a simple c++ code that demonstrate the problem:

```
namespace Space {
  class Base1 {
      public:
    virtual void Method1() = 0;
   };
  class Base2 {
    public:
    virtual void Method2();
  };
  class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
    public:
    virtual void Method1();
  };
}
```

The code above represents what I want to wrap in JAVA.

When I run Swig on the above example, it creates Base1 as an Interface (as it should)

```
public interface Base1 {
  long Base1_GetInterfaceCPtr();
  void Method1();
}
```

And declares (in JAVA) the derived class extending Base2 and implementing Base1 (as it also should), **BUT** , it DOES NOT create a java method inside the Derived class that implements the interface Base1 ( Method1 inside Derived) the full Derived Java class generated is as follows:

```
public class Derived extends Base2 implements Base1 {
  private transient long swigCPtr;

  protected Derived(long cPtr, boolean cMemoryOwn) {
    super(SOURCEIJNI.Derived_SWIGUpcast(cPtr), cMemoryOwn);
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(Derived obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }

  protected void finalize() {
    delete();
  }

  public synchronized void delete() {
    if (swigCPtr != 0) {
      if (swigCMemOwn) {
        swigCMemOwn = false;
        SOURCEIJNI.delete_Derived(swigCPtr);
      }
      swigCPtr = 0;
    }
    super.delete();
  }

  public long Base1_GetInterfaceCPtr() {
    return SOURCEIJNI.Derived_Base1_GetInterfaceCPtr(swigCPtr);
  }

  public Derived() {
    this(SOURCEIJNI.new_Derived(), true);
  }
}
```

And so, Im stuck with a Java compilation error of a SWIG generated class (Derived) that does not implement all methods of its interface (Base1)

What am I missing? I've read the documentation and should work...

My ".i" file: (using swig 3.0.10)

```
%module SOURCEI

%include <swiginterface.i>
%interface_impl(Space::Base1);

%{
#include "Source.h"
%}
%include "Source.h"
```

Comment: If I remove the "= 0" for pure virtual and remove the declaration of method1 in Derived, it does work. But for my project, i cannot change the ".h"s.
`namespace Space {
  class Base1 {
      public:
    virtual void Method1();
   };
  class Base2 {
    public:
    virtual void Method2();
  };
  class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
  };
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using swig 3.0.2 and it works perfect for me. I do not have the file `swiginterface.i`. My Java installation is a little screwed up so I tried with Python and Ruby. For both languages, I have made a slightly different interface file.

```
%module example
%{
  #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  #include "Source.h"
%}

%interface_impl(Space::Base1);

%include "Source.h"
```

The header file I have equipped with default'ed virtual destructors.

```
namespace Space {
  class Base1 {
  public:
    virtual void Method1() = 0;
    virtual ~Base1() = default;
   };
  class Base2 {
    public:
    virtual void Method2();
    virtual ~Base2() = default;
  };
  class Derived : public Base1, public Base2 {
    public:
    virtual void Method1();
  };
}
```

I just tried it with Java and I do get a method inside Derived

```
 public void Method1() {
     exampleJNI.Derived_Method1(swigCPtr, this);
 }
```

I compile the above as follows

```
swig -java -c++ Source.i
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -c Source.cpp Source_wrap.cxx -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/
g++ -std=c++11 -fPIC -shared Source.o  Source_wrap.o -o libShared.so
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i try with your .i and your .h and it gives the same error. I downloaded swig 3.0.2 and it gives the error     "Warning 813: Warning for Space::Derived proxy: Base Space::Base2 ignored. Multiple inheritance is not supported in Java." 
How do you call swig on the command line?
I use:
swig.exe -package teste.sourcepackage -small -v  -outdir temp -c++ -java -o temp/SOURCEJAVA_wrap.cxx Source.i

Comment: I run on windows (download the precompiled windows distribution)

Comment: Found the Problem.... its the "-small" command... I used it because my wrapper became big and I read somewhere that it compacted the generated wrapper... but it does more than that " -small          - Compile in virtual elimination & compact mode" I guess the "virtual elimination" part is ignoring the pure virtual methods...  I changed "-small" to "-fcompact" and it seams to be working now!!!

Comment: @BernardoFrankenfeld Glad you found the error. I run `swig -java -c++ Source.i`